# Issues in Ruby script using oauth2 to access API hosted on Azure AD

Tags: ruby, azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Ruby version: 2.4.1p111

I have a ruby script that I was trying out by copying the Bearer token and then passing in the request to the application API I am want to access. This works fine and now I want to enhance the script by taking out my bearer token hack and instead get a token through oauth to access the API.
The API is hosted on Azure as an App Service. I have the following information:
1. client_id
2. client_secret
3. Site address: https://login.microsoftonline.com/someapp.com
4. Redirect_uri: https://someapp/login

I used gem 'oauth2' and followed the example on the gem wiki page. Following is what I do:
Gem wiki page: https://github.com/intridea/oauth2

---

```
require 'oauth2'

#Initializing a client
client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', :site 
=>'https://login.microsoftonline.com/someapp.com')

#Creating a auth url
auth_url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri 
=>'https://someapp/login')

#After auth_url is created, I then send a request to access the token
token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', :redirect_uri 
=> 'https://someapp/login', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic 
some_password'})
response = token.get('/api/resource', :params => { 'query_foo' => 'bar' })
```

---

1. What I don’t understand is what is the 'authorization_code_value' parameter in the token request?
2. The headers options hash says 'Authorization'=>'Basic some password'. What would this be for and what to put here
3. Another thing I noticed is that the gem when creating the auth_url takes away the name of the application from the site address and creates the url starting with: https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth/authorize. This is incorrect as when I copy paste this url in browser, it does not open. However the correct url would be: https://login.microsoftonline.com/someapp.com/oauth2/authorize. When I use this in browser, I am presented with the microsoft login, where after entering credentials the user is redirected to our application and login is successful.

In summary, what I would want to do is get a token in my script and then use that token to make requests to the API. Is this the right gem to use? Or a better / simpler approach to achieve this?

Please let me know if more info is required. Looking forward on help guidance from you guys on this. Have spent couple of days and I am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.What I don’t understand is what is the 'authorization_code_value' parameter in the token request?

This parameter is used in the [code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code). This flow is used for web app or the native client for mobile. please ensure that you were using this flow if you want to use this parameter.

> The headers options hash says 'Authorization'=>'Basic some password'. What would this be for and what to put here

The OAuth 2.0 required to send the token with the format like `Authorization: bearer {access_token}`. More detail, you can refer the link below:

[Use the access token to access the resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-access-token-to-access-the-resource)

> Another thing I noticed is that the gem when creating the auth_url takes away the name of the application from the site address and creates the url starting with: https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth/authorize. This is incorrect as when I copy paste this url in browser, it does not open. However the correct url would be: https://login.microsoftonline.com/someapp.com/oauth2/authorize. When I use this in browser, I am presented with the microsoft login, where after entering credentials the user is redirected to our application and login is successful.

The correct authorize endpoint should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize`, refer the [OpenID Connect metadata document](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration).  And [this link](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration) is for the [Azure AD V2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview).

*The {tenant} value in the path of the request can be used to control who can sign into the application. The allowed values are tenant identifiers, for example, 8eaef023-2b34-4da1-9baa-8bc8c9d6a490 or contoso.onmicrosoft.com or common for tenant-independent tokens*

And below link is also very helpful for understanding developing with Azure AD:

[Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios)

Comment: thanks for the response. I am trying to use the Ruby ADAL library from microsoft. It seems like the oauth2 gem is not updated and hence it is creating the incorrect authorize endpoint. I will update how things went with ADAL library